# How long should I wait before trying to modify the DOM on page load?

Tags: jquery

I want to append some elements to the DOM as soon as the page is ready. I tried putting this in a function called on `$(document).ready()`, but if I do that, looking up the element with `$('#id')` fails. If I wait and execute the same exact command via the console or using a timeout, then it succeeds.

I don't have any fancy fonts or images at this stage in development, and modifying the DOM shouldn't rely on CSS loading. Is `$(document).ready()` really too soon to modify the DOM? What should I use instead?

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
var thing = {
  init: function(){
    this.add('Thing 1', 'thing1', 'id1');
    this.add('Thing 2', 'thing2', 'id2');
  },
  add: function(name, dom_id, type){
    var box = $('<div/>', {id: dom_id, 'class': 'item-box'});
    box.append($('<div/>', {'class': 'item-name', text: name}));
    var container = $('#' + type);
    container.append(box);
  }
};
$(document).ready(thing.init());
```

In the html, the items with ids `id1` and `id2` are statically defined. The line that fails is `var container = $('#' + type);`. I originally had this call in-line but separated it out for debugging. `container` is undefined at this point in the code.

If I run the `add` function later via the command line or a timeout, it works fine.

Comment: What's #id element? It could be created by a script which runs at document.ready.

Comment: The element I'm trying to select is in the html source.

Comment: You should be able to modify the DOM safely in `$(document).ready()`. If it's not working then you're doing something wrong. Posting some code would help a lot.

Comment: @MikeW I added the relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
$(document).ready(thing.init());
```

Runs `thing.init()` immediately and the return value is then passed to `.ready()` which isn't very useful :)

You will want to wrap the call in an anonymous function, so that it runs only when the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    thing.init();
});
```

Alternatively, use the slightly shorter version:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    thing.init();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.onload to execute a script as soon as the page is actually loaded:

```
window.onload = function() {
   //Code Here
};
```

Comment: That's when the document and everything else has been loaded; in many cases, the DOM itself is loaded way before that time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DOMContentLoaded to execute a code as soon as DOM is loaded

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    //Code Here
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready()` fires when the HTML content has loaded, whereas `$(window).load()` waits for **all** assets to load.

Where "safe" means *everything* is loaded, `$(window).load()` is what you're looking for.

The below illustrates `load` firing after `ready`:

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3nn5u0k4/

#### Markup

```
<div id="debug">
  <!--load times in millisecons get appended here-->
</div>
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/Very_Large_Array,_2012.jpg"/>
```

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var t = new Date();
    t = t.getUTCMilliseconds();
    $('#debug').append('<p>HTML document loaded: ' + t + '</p>');
});

$(window).load(function(){
    var t = new Date();
    t = t.getUTCMilliseconds();
    $('#debug').append('<p>HTML document loaded: ' + t + '</p>');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use setTimeout()

```
setTimeout(function(){
   alert("execute your action now...")
}, 1000);
```

This is what I'm guessing reading your post. But it would have been better if you had your code in your post.

EDIT:

now that the OP post the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    thing.init();
});
```

Comment: Not necessary, and it introduces an unnecessary 1000ms delay in the loading sequence. `$(document).ready()` should be enough.

Comment: @MikeW: Yep, looking at OPs post that's what I could guess. Need the code to give a propper answer...